# How in laravel 5.7 to run several urls on the same control action?

Tags: laravel-5

Which is valid way in laravel 5.7 to run several urls on the same control action, like

```
Route::get('about', array(
    'as'      => 'page-about',
    'uses'    => 'PageController@page_content'
))->AdditiveParameter('about');



Route::get('security', array(
    'as'      => 'page-security',
    'uses'    => 'PageController@page_content'
))->AdditiveParameter('security');
```

and In PageController page_content action have 1 required parameter ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for this only, but hope it will give some idea.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{prefix?}', 'where' => ['prefix' => 'content']],function (){
Route::get('{route_name}/{req_param}', array(
'as'      => 'page-security',
'uses'    => 'PageController@page_content'
))->where('route_name', '(about|security)');
});
```

And Controller action will be something like this

```
public function page_content($route_name,$req_param)
{
}
```

Let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: In your case how url must look like ?
I tried http://local-votes.com/content/about, where http://local-votes.com is root of my site
and got  "invalid url" error 

Also I would like to get url http://local-votes.com/about, without content/ prefix...

Comment: @Ivan I tried this with my ```local environment```. So my url was like ```http://localhost/testproject/public/about/req_param```. Where ```req_param``` is your required parameter. Do you want ```content``` prefix optional?

Comment: Yes, better without prefix, like ocal-votes.com/about

Comment: @Ivan I have added code for optional ```prefix```. If it`s show you invalid ```url``` then just check how rest of your ```url``` are defined. Because I am trying this is on my ```local environment``` so after ```/public/``` my ```uri``` is working

Comment: Alas, it does not for me.